# How to add mouselistener on random drawn image in java?

Tags: java, swing, random, drawimage, mouse-listeners

I am building a game in Java and I need to add a mouselistener to an random drawn image in my game.

I made the image appear on random places every x seconds, when I click the image I would like to add 1 point to the scoreboard.

My code for the random image adding is:

```
Random rand = new Random();
private int x = 0;
private int y = 0;

Timer timer = new Timer(700, new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        x = rand.nextInt(400);
        y = rand.nextInt(330);
        repaint();
    }
});

public void mousePressed (MouseEvent me) {
       // Do something here
       repaint();
     }

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawImage(achtergrond, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
    //g.drawImage(muisje, 10, 10, null);
    g.drawImage(muisje, x, y, 100, 100, this);
}
```

I looked on google and found that I need to add a new class with a mouse event, but How do I add this? It's not clear enough because I'm just a beginner in Java.

Comment: You need to set your mouse listener implementation to the component you're drawing the image at. Since you seem to be implementing everything in the same classe I guess you could do this.addMouseListener(this); 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Comment: As you can see I have two images, achtergrond (background) and muisje (mouse/rat) I only need the mouse event on the second image(muisje) So I don't think it's working with a mouselistener on the jpanel.

Comment: You could solve it both ways: drawing the images to different components and adding your mouse listener to both of them, or adding your mouse listener to the component that draws everything and checking the images boundaries to figure out which image the mouse is over (like @StuPointerException said).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register a `MouseListener` for your `Gamevenster` class. Instead of making the class implement `MouseListener`, just use a `MouseAdapter`, where you only have to implement the method `mouseClicked`. So in your constructor, you something like this

```
private JLabel scoreLabel = new JLabel("Score: " + score);
private int score = 0;

public Gamevenster() {
    scoreLabel.setFont(new Font("impact", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    scoreLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    add(scoreLabel);

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            Point p = e.getPoint();
            int clickX = (int)p.getX();
            int clickY = (int)p.getY();

            if(clickX > x && clickX < x + 100 && clickY > y && clickY  < y + 100) {
                score++;
                scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This helped me a lot :) When I click the image, I get a score now! when I click not on the image nothing is done with the score! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You know where the image is drawn (x,y) and you know the size of the image (100,100), therefore to tell if the mouse click is inside the image you can do something like this:

```
public void mousePressed (MouseEvent me) {
    int clickX = me.getXOnScreen();
    int clickY = me.getYOnScreen();


    if(clickX > x && clickX < x+100 && clickY > y && clickY  < y+100) {
        //the image has been clicked
    }
    repaint();
}
```

The class you're writing can then implement `MouseListener`.

**EDIT in response to comment:**

You don't need to link the code to the image, the component that you're writing should implement the mouse listener since this maintains the state and knows where the image is drawn.  I would start out by looking at this link and implementing a basic MouseListener to print out the x and y co-ordinates of mouse clicks on your component:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

**Example component implementing Mouse Listener:**

```
public class TestComponent extends JComponent implements MouseListener {

    public TestComponent() {
        this.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int clickedX = e.getX();
        int clickedY = e.getY();

        System.out.println("User Clicked: " + clickedX + ", " + clickedY);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to link this event to the image, I'm new to Java. It's not that easy to understand the code.

Comment: I really can't figure out how to do this :/

Comment: I've added a basic example to the answer.

Comment: I've added your example code to my project and tried it, but I don't get a system.out.